# Docker disk usage

Tags: docker

I am hosting some simple docker containers. I am wondering that the container size is increasing over time quickly and I do not know how to figure out the problem.

Size reported by Docker:

```
me@somewhere:~$ sudo docker ps -s
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES               SIZE
02b30add1cb3        my-service               "npm start"              23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         3001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9017->9017/tcp   my-service-frontend      0 B (virtual 776.4 MB)
20a2be4931e7        my-service               "phantomjs src/sites/"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:3007->3001/tcp             my-service-5     6.144 kB (virtual 776.4 MB)
ba340ba08941        my-service               "phantomjs src/sites/"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:3006->3001/tcp             my-service-4     6.144 kB (virtual 776.4 MB)
7b5411d8a171        my-service               "phantomjs src/sites/"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:3003->3001/tcp             my-service-1     6.144 kB (virtual 776.4 MB)
b583a544b37d        my-service               "phantomjs src/sites/"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp             my-service-0     6.144 kB (virtual 776.4 MB)
91373086e06e        foo_bar                  "/bin/sh -c 'git pull"   47 hours ago        Up 47 hours         0.0.0.0:12776->8080/tcp            kickass_murdock     11.26 MB (virtual 1.081 GB)
```

Size reported by `du` on host:

```
me@somewhere:~$ sudo du -h -d 1 /var/lib/docker/containers
14G     /var/lib/docker/containers/20a2be4931e7a10b2e29260b541e3c4d6581462650e47d59682f84626843752b
1,6G    /var/lib/docker/containers/7b5411d8a171a35a3c937d62dbdea141fc0a9f3c4de25a2da3a0b94ea71a8f3d
9,6M    /var/lib/docker/containers/02b30add1cb3ba6d5be1c36b2c9dd141d8d70cb88a021d2363af5684ef3c220f
480K    /var/lib/docker/containers/91373086e06ea83269465e0b026cfe7ca0158a1315b0df04da9a1d1b4ee52823
13G /var/lib/docker/containers/b583a544b37db6144f17a4819ca2f636126b11d668caab3dcdbf4c3a33dedc65
13G /var/lib/docker/containers/ba340ba08941d47af45230be328ef7289c19b6bb6a0d120cf2098cbdd9983f65
40G /var/lib/docker/containers`
```

Size reported by `du` for a container (similar output for all other containers):

```
me@somewhere:~$ sudo docker exec -it my-service-4 du -h -d1 -c /
58M /root
0   /dev
3.0M    /etc
706M    /usr
1.4M    /tmp
14M /var
9.0M    /bin
32M /lib
4.0K    /home
8.0K    /run
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /boot
0   /sys
4.0K    /opt
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /lib64
3.9M    /sbin
du: cannot access '/proc/12642/task/12642/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12642/task/12642/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12642/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12642/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
4.0K    /media
825M    /
825M    total
```

So: Both the container and `docker ps` report disk usage below 1G, though the actual container file size is more than 10 GB (at least for some). Can any body help me and tell what is happening? I guess there is some trouble going on within my container, though I do not know where to look right now. Anybody knows what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Docker put one layer over the other in its onion file system whenever changes are stored to an image. When you delete your container `docker rmi -f CONTAINERID`, you should see that /var/lib/docker/containers uses less space.

Changes to an image are stored when you build it. If you just use an image - run a container - the changed data is just "hold". So you should investigate what happens IN your container. Esp. see what your phantom server produces in the filesystem. [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) would be a good tool for that.

Start with ncdu and then store the files that are produced in an attached folder of your hosts filesystem. `docker run -it -v FULLPATHATHOST:FULLPATHWITHINCONTAINER CONTAINERID`

**Test**

run a simple container, containing nothing more than the os (in my case alpine)

```
docker run -it stk/alpine:base sh
```

At the host go to `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/` and list the containing directories with ncdu. (Of course you can use any other program you like to determine the diretories sizes)

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                    
--- /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff --------------------------------------------------
                        /..                                                     
  286,4MiB [##########] /39f3e2ea0dfe17366b8cd7b0...bf3681b99a1081e33ad62a509f28
  214,3MiB [#######   ] /2de39307b9361cae12f0116e...d28056e4699b21b9a4d34f374461
  207,7MiB [#######   ] /92ec6d044cb3e39ae0050012...78d0591675f2231daafbf0877778
  154,0MiB [#####     ] /9f3806e6bedc8fb01929131b...e01aa1980aadba914fdd9d2f96ae
  149,5MiB [#####     ] /5f0ca2331640639507d85b83...693659438367311abb0c792b8a62
  136,8MiB [####      ] /902b87aaaec929e805414868...1f529ad7f37ab300d4ef9f3a0dbf
  136,2MiB [####      ] /222ba86561913d299deb9e0e...6b5f5ec117b01386a4156d092687
  132,6MiB [####      ] /8b3a9a9eeaf8ed59f24f21a2...dfe8d033890a2fa44b445deb2e3c
  128,5MiB [####      ] /72b3edf317a8d682466c1500...a5e2cad31c8305ed42c41cd61149
  117,0MiB [####      ] /818e3763e72ef82b28b0552e...b9f163dc601d266e94e46fd26bb0
   57,4MiB [##        ] /eeffdfafed9f60771b5bf87a...e8bbd16b572f77899c8e689d174d
   56,1MiB [#         ] /6976ce3ed5fab37382d90467...37578332417ffcf35a1d499eba52
   51,3MiB [#         ] /a5a6e0549d247f1c8b81a350...c5071f46d17afe2f8988817360b3
 Total disk usage:   2,7GiB  Apparent size:   2,7GiB  Items: 168658
```

Within the container execute something like

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 409600000 > a.txt && ls a.txt -all -h
```

that will create a file with random data called `a.txt` I choosed the size `409600000` to be greater than 286,4MiB - the largest folder in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/` - so that ncdu shall show it on top

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                    
--- /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff --------------------------------------------------
                        /..                                                     
  390,6MiB [##########] /0720a07653a57d938c861cf3...e61c81c29f12289759f0560aa38f
  286,4MiB [#######   ] /39f3e2ea0dfe17366b8cd7b0...bf3681b99a1081e33ad62a509f28
  214,3MiB [#####     ] /2de39307b9361cae12f0116e...d28056e4699b21b9a4d34f374461
  207,7MiB [#####     ] /92ec6d044cb3e39ae0050012...78d0591675f2231daafbf0877778
  154,0MiB [###       ] /9f3806e6bedc8fb01929131b...e01aa1980aadba914fdd9d2f96ae
  149,5MiB [###       ] /5f0ca2331640639507d85b83...693659438367311abb0c792b8a62
  136,8MiB [###       ] /902b87aaaec929e805414868...1f529ad7f37ab300d4ef9f3a0dbf
  136,2MiB [###       ] /222ba86561913d299deb9e0e...6b5f5ec117b01386a4156d092687
  132,6MiB [###       ] /8b3a9a9eeaf8ed59f24f21a2...dfe8d033890a2fa44b445deb2e3c
  128,5MiB [###       ] /72b3edf317a8d682466c1500...a5e2cad31c8305ed42c41cd61149
  117,0MiB [##        ] /818e3763e72ef82b28b0552e...b9f163dc601d266e94e46fd26bb0
   57,4MiB [#         ] /eeffdfafed9f60771b5bf87a...e8bbd16b572f77899c8e689d174d
   56,1MiB [#         ] /6976ce3ed5fab37382d90467...37578332417ffcf35a1d499eba52
 Total disk usage:   3,0GiB  Apparent size:   3,0GiB  Items: 168678
```

Now I know that it's the directory starting with `0720a07653a57d9...` is that I have to look for. Go into it and list the content

```
root@T520:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff# cd 0720a07653a57d938c861cf32f4bee87fa4be61c81c29f12289759f0560aa38f
root@T520:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/0720a07653a57d938c861cf32f4bee87fa4be61c81c29f12289759f0560aa38f# ls -all -h
insgesamt 391M
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4,0K Feb 23 10:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 674 root root  80K Feb 23 10:55 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 391M Feb 23 10:57 a.txt
drwx------   2 root root 4,0K Feb 23 10:55 root
-r--r--r--   1 root root    0 Feb 23 10:55 .wh..wh.aufs
drwx------   2 root root 4,0K Feb 23 10:55 .wh..wh.orph
drwx------   2 root root 4,0K Feb 23 10:55 .wh..wh.plnk
```

As you can see, there is the file `a.txt` listed.

Now rerun the procedure, random file creation and relist ncdu (just hit `r` in ncdu.)

`ncdu` should show you, as well as `ls` should do, that the directory size did not change. So the data within the docker fs is just overwritten. If you choose a smale size it gets smaller.

**So how might this help you?**
As I showed above there is no file growth for changing data within files. And you can find out witch directory contains you filesystem and see the plain filestructure of added/changed files within your container.

Hope this helps to find the files within your container.

If you exit your container and restart it by the same command again, a new instance is created, with it own fs layer is created.

You can find the ids of your stopped containers use

```
docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep stk/alpine:base | awk '{print $1 }'
```

To see what is found before deleteing...

```
docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep stk/alpine:base

7b7d3f6e857a        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      22 minutes ago      Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                          gigantic_swartz
2f51ea988a28        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      23 minutes ago      Exited (0) 22 minutes ago                         cranky_euler
4bfafbb034fe        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      34 minutes ago      Exited (0) 25 minutes ago                         sick_williams
80cd5687fcd7        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      44 minutes ago      Exited (137) 37 minutes ago                       determined_panini
a2179a8dd543        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      58 minutes ago      Exited (130) 44 minutes ago                       agitated_shockley
8596cd310292        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      3 days ago          Exited (137) 3 days ago                           dreamy_murdock
33db61a7830b        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      3 days ago          Exited (0) 3 days ago                             desperate_hodgkin
2f96c15dc8a1        stk/alpine:base           "sh"                      2 weeks ago         Exited (0) 2 weeks ago                            determined_babbage
```

Attach `| xargs -r docker rm` to delete them

**One line solution**

```
docker ps -a | grep Exited | grep stk/alpine:base | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs -r docker rm
```

*Docker will check that the images are not used by other images and complain if it can't be removed if you do `docker rmi`. But in this case you want the containers and not the images to be deleted. So use `rm` instead of `rmi` (I updated the answer)*

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the disk space is freed again when I remove my containers. The issue is that I cannot find any files that are created in my container. I use `sudo docker exec -it my-service-4 du -h -d1 -c /` in order to investigate the disk usage of my running container. This disk usage remains constant over the whole time, though the container in /var/lib/docker/containers is increasing nevertheless.